# Calendar widget/activity with events

Tags: android, calendar

Can someone help me make an activity that shows a calendar with multiple events shown in its date cell.
I have tried many sample codes from medium and other portals like https://applandeo.com/blog/material-calendar-view-customized-calendar-widget-android/
but none works well.